# border-radius disappears while animating

Tags: css, webkit

I'm trying to emulate a certain kind of menu that can be seen in iOS with CSS. It has menu items in a `ul`, and clicking each one makes the menu slide over to reveal the page.

However, whenever the menu is sliding (while it's *actively* sliding) the corners turn square. Then they go back to being rounded after animation is finished.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xes0wyu/4/) with a lot of my superfluous styling code cut out. If you click on either of the titles in the list, you'll see that the corners turn square just as the content is animating. This can be seen again when you press the back button.

I see this issue in the latest Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give #modal-content a z-index of 1 (assuming nothing below it has a z-index greater than 1) and it should keep the border-radius during the transition.

```
.modal-content {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;top:0;left:0;right:0;
  margin: 10vh;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

By making .modal-content higher in the element stack, when the transition happens the child elements of .modal-content are moving "underneath" .modal-content. So .modal-contents border isn't obscured by the transitioning child.

Comment: Why is this? Can you elaborate? It works, I'm just wondering why.

Comment: By making .modal-content higher in the element stack, when the transition happens the child elements of .modal-content are moving "underneath" .modal-content. So .modal-content's border isn't obscured by the transitioning child. As to why this seems to be a problem with webkit browsers, I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah. Want to add this to your answer? I'll accept it then.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll add it.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that. Approved!